# Facebook php-sdk v4 get friends ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

How can I get friends ID with SDK V4?

Below don't work...

```
   $friends = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends'))
    ->execute()
    ->getGraphObject()
    ->asArray();
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {    
     echo 'Name: ' . $friend['name'] . '<br />';
        echo 'ID: ' . $friend['id'] . '<br /><br />';
        $counter++;

}
```

Comment: "it does not work" - oh how i love it when people write THAT instead of a serious description...

Comment: Sorry for my poor english... :)

Answer (score 1):

With the new Graph API v2.0, you need to ask for the `user_friends` permission in order to get friend information. Also, this method no longer returns all the user's friends. It only returns a list of friends who also use the same application.

[See this article for more information](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/).